# How to ask someone in German about their health?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

*Wie geht's* or *Wie geht es Ihnen* is more of a general *How are you doing* according to my understanding.

But if I know someone who was not keeping well, then how could I ask about their health? Basically, the translation of "How's your health now"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wie geht es Ihnen **gesundheitlich**? *(plain)*

That simple. Or add some colour with particles.

> Wie geht es Ihnen **denn** gesundheitlich? *(curious)*

---

You can add the topic you are interested in with an adjective corresponding to a noun in "adverb-mode".

> Wie geht es Ihnen beruflich?
>
> Wie geht es Ihnen finanziell?
>
> Wie geht es Ihnen familiär?

Answer (score 0):

Umgangssprachlich:

"Was macht die Gesundheit?"

oder gleich spezifisch:

"Was macht die Prostata/der Hals/die Leber?"

Natürlich unter Berücksichtigung eventueller Mithörer und Privatsphärenaspekten.

Jemand der längere Zeit krank war und weiß, dass Du weisst, dass er krank war, wird die Frage "Wie geht es Ihnen" aber wahrscheinlich von selbst auf die Gesundheit beziehen.